# Energy needed to pump air through a tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air

I have 10 hollow plastic tubes, which may bend, each 10 cm long but with different internal diameters ranging from 2mm, 2.5mm, 3 mm ... upto 6.5mm. I need to pass through them 500ml of room air with 250 ml/sec speed. How can I calculate the resistance of each tube? In other words how tube resistance depends on internal diameter? How much energy it takes to pump 500 ml of air through each one of the tubes?

Comment: What is your background in fluid mechanics?

Comment: I have studied some basic physics in a university, but have no background in fluid mechanics. We are trying to make some calculations for airway tubes for use in operating room.

Comment: You need to hire yourself a fluid mechanics consultant.  Doing this properly requires some fluid mechanics expertise.